# Split list in almost equal parts and return bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I would like to split a list and return the bounds so in extend no single element should exist.

E.g

```
split(list(range(1,101)),2) 
# should return 
[[1,50],[51,100]]

split(list(range(1,101)),3)
# should return
[[1,33],[34,66],[67,100]]

split(list(range(1,6)),3)
# should return
[[1,2],[3,5]] # Ideally last element should merge with last if last one has no pair.
```

So far I tried

```
def split(l, n):
    x = list(range(1, l+1))
    return [x[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(x), int(len(x)/n))]

print(split(20, 2))
```

which returns `[[1, 2], [11, 12]]` instead of `[[1, 10], [11, 20]]`

Comment: It is because, first time the value of i is 0 . so, it will take x[0:2] so the value for that position will be 1 and 2 respectively  and for next loop it will be 11 and 12.I hope this will help you to rethink on your logic part.

Comment: so the function you called in print statement is typo or you forget to mention it?

Comment: Your examples will never occur, range(1,100) returns [1..99] should that be range(1, 101)?

Comment: Example corrected @Tim

Comment: Should this assume the input is always sorted? Or can the function accept any range?

Comment: It will always be sorted @Tim

Comment: Can you explain why split(20, 2) should include the top of the range while the rest do not?

Comment: I really feel like your expected results are incorrect for several of these, if not just inconsistent.

Comment: @pylang the list from 1-6 contains: 1,2,3,4,5 so when we split in 2 its should be [[1,3],[4,5]] or [[1,2],[3,5]]

Comment: But in your question you split into 3.

Comment: Shouldn't `split(list(range(1,6)),3)` give 3 splits, not two?

Comment: @pylang `range(1,6)` == `[1,2,3,4,5]` - if split in 3 you get `[ [1,2], [3,4]. [5,None]` - there should be no "rangeless" ones in the result - instead the range before it gets extended - hence `[[1,2],[3,5]]`

Comment: @PanosKal. kindly clear your test case `split(list(range(1,6)),3)` resulting in to `[[1,2],[3,5]]`

Comment: Please check Patrick's comment, above yours, to understand why the last range is extended @Gahan

Comment: @PanosKal then answer you accepted isn't satisfying that condition, chrisz still believes it's a typo by you

Comment: @Gahan I made explicit request in the first line "...no single element should exist". Chris gave a perfect answer. I did change the code to comply to my needs. I'll edit the example.

Comment: @PanosKal check the conversation I had under his answer, I couldn't make sure it is satisfying the question needs, so if you are saying it's perfect answer then it's based on considering a typo for your case list of `[1,2,3,4,5]` results in `[[1,2], [3,5]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def csplit(m,n):
    div_ = m//n
    step = div_ if div_ > 1 else 2  # determine step for range function (at least 2 'alternate steps')
    lis = []
    for i in range(1, m+1, step):
        if (m-(i+max(1, div_-1))) > 1:
            # append list only if remains at least two elements remains 
            lis.append([i,i+max(1, div_-1)])
        else:
            if not m == i:
                # in case if m and i not equal and not more then one element left then construct list which include that element
                lis.append([i, m])
            break  # break the loop from iterating any further
    return lis

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(csplit(100, 2))
    print(csplit(100, 3))
    print(csplit(5, 3))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 50], [51, 100]]
[[1, 33], [34, 66], [67, 100]]
[[1, 2], [3, 5]]
```

---

A one liner for the same:

```
def csplit(m,n):
    return [[i,i+max(1, m//n-1)] if (m-(i+max(1, m//n-1))) > 1 else [i, m] for i in range(1, m+1, max(m//n, 2)) if not i==m]
```

Comment: @chrisz I had variable not included in second function(updated) but no syntax error..

Comment: I merged yours with Chrisz answer. I did favored speed that is why I accepted Chrisz's answer at first. Thanks for your help and sorry if I misjudged

Comment: @PanosKal; you can post your own answer too in this thread. I'd like to see other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very fast solution, the one caveat being that the longest of the sub-lists will be last instead of first (however groups will still be as even as they can be):

```
def fast_chunks(start, stop, chunks):
  l = math.ceil(((stop-start)/chunks)-1)
  fin = []
  for j in range(chunks-1):
    fin.append([start, start+l])
    start += l + 1
  fin.append([start, stop])
  return fin
```

In action:

```
In [41]: fast_chunks(1, 100, 2)
Out[41]: [[1, 50], [51, 100]]

In [42]: fast_chunks(1, 100, 3)
Out[42]: [[1, 33], [34, 66], [67, 100]]

In [43]: fast_chunks(1, 6, 2)
Out[43]: [[1, 3], [4, 6]]
```

Simple solution using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [`np.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
def _split(start, stop, n):
    return [[i[0], i[-1]] for i in np.array_split(np.arange(start, stop+1), n)]
```

In action:

```
In [54]: _split(1, 20, 2)
Out[54]: [[1, 10], [11, 20]]

In [55]: _split(1, 100, 2)
Out[55]: [[1, 50], [51, 100]]

In [56]: _split(1, 6, 2)
Out[56]: [[1, 3], [4, 6]]
```

With timings, `fast_chunks` outperforms the others by quite a bit:

```
In [45]: %timeit chrisz_fast_chunks(1, 1000000, 100)
24.5 µs ± 496 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [27]: %timeit artner_split(1000000, 100)
58 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit gahan_split(1000000, 100)
77 µs ± 280 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit chrisz_split(1, 1000000, 100)
1.77 ms ± 39.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [24]: %timeit pylang_split(1000000, 100)
72 ms ± 445 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help, it is not useing the full range of list, but just the "borders" you are interested in, some creative `zip()`ping and fixes whats wrong after creating the ranges:

```
def split(l, n):
    stride =(l//n)
    r = list(range(1, l+stride, stride))  # overbuild needed range

    # adjust zipped value by 1 if needed
    k = [ [a , b-1 ] for a,b in zip(r,r[1:]) ]

    # fix special cases 
    for _ in range(n+1): # guesstimate of fixes needed

        if k[-1][0] == k[-1][1]: # last pair identical 
            k.pop()    # remove it and fix new last index to be l  instead
            k[-1][1] = l        
        elif k[-1][1] != l:
            k[-1][1] = l

    return k

print(split(100, 2))
print(split(100, 4))
print(split(103, 3))
print(split(6, 3))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 50], [51, 100]]                          # split(100, 2)
[[1, 25], [26, 50], [51, 75], [76, 100]]      # split(100, 4)
[[1, 34], [35, 68], [69, 103]]                # split(103, 3)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]                      # split(6, 3)
```

I gave it a cursory testing with your examples, check the logic if it fits all your special cases.

Especially the `# guesstimate of fixes needed` might be too many... I have a hunch that at most 2 should be enough

Comment: @chrisz thanks for the timings :) - still feel its kindof cheating

Comment: @chrisz - typo: split(6,3) resulted in [1,3],[4,6] - fixed now and simplified the zipping as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe your expected results are inconsistent, but here is something simple that may help you.

Using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.divide), a third-party library (install via `> pip install more_itertools`):

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


def split(val, n):
    """Return a list of equally divided intervals."""
    a = [list(c)[0] for c in mit.divide(n, range(1, val+1))]
    b = [list(c)[-1] for c in mit.divide(n, range(1, val+1))]
    return list(zip(a, b))
```

**Demo**

```
split(100, 2)
# [(1, 50), (51, 100)]

split(99, 3)
# [(1, 33), (34, 66), (67, 99)]

split(100, 3)
# [(1, 34), (35, 67), (68, 100)]

split(20, 2)
# [(1, 10), (11, 20)]
```